# Raspberry pi 3 model B+ を VPN サーバにしたい

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn

サーバマシン：Raspberry pi 3 model B+, OS:2019-07-10-raspbian-buster-full
クライアント：Android 5.1(スマホ)
ドメイン名は MyDNS.jp で取得。https://viral-community.com/other-it/ddns-mydns-2060/

win32 disk imager で microsd カードに OS を焼き、root ユーザにパスワードを設定、pi ユーザのユーザ名及びパスワード変更をシェルから行い、デスクトップの設定画面からホスト名も変更しました。
そして上記の環境で下記サイトに従って VPN 接続を試してみたところ、ローカルネットワークからは繋がりましたが、外部ネットワークからアクセスできません。
設定は次のサイトの設定をほぼ全てコピーしました。
https://vogel.at.webry.info/201901/article_6.html

変えた部分は
/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf
の ip range, local ip と username, passward,
/etc/ipsec.secrets
の PSK の値だけです。
local ip は wimax ルータ wifi 2 next wx03 から DHCP 機能で設定して割り当てているローカル ip の値を入れ、 ip range も最後尾の3桁以外 local ip に合わせました。
例えばローカルipが 〇〇〇.△△△.✕✕✕.??? のとき、
ip range は 〇〇〇.△△△.✕✕✕.***～のように設定しています。
ユーザ名とパスワードと事前共有鍵は、好きな値を入力しました。
それ以外の値は変えていません。

Android スマホの標準機能でローカルネットワーク上から、設定したユーザ名とパスワードと事前共有鍵と、サーバのローカル ip アドレスやログイン名を入力したら、ラズパイに vpn 接続できました。
次にスマホのデータ通信回線(外部のネットワーク)を使い、サーバアドレスに取得したドメイン名(○○.mydns.jp)を入れましたが、接続できません。

上記サイトの設定は Ubuntu 向けの設定でしたが、ラズパイでも動いたので、あとは細かい部分の設定を変えればいいのではないかと思ったのですが、どこを触ればいいかわかりません。

SoftEther VPN での設定も試みましたがうまくいきませんでした。
次のサイトに従い Windows マシンからラズパイに接続しようとしたら、アクセスが拒否されてしまい、そこから先に進めず。
https://chibashi.me/development/softether-vpn-server-201902/
仕方なく strongswan xl2tpd で VPN しようと思った次第です。

ラズパイを使って strongswan, xl2tpd を使う方法を記したサイトも他にいくつかあったのですが、何を間違ったのか、今の所他のサイトの方法ではうまくいっていません。

ちなみにルータ(wx03)の機能で、ラズパイのローカル ip にポートマッピング設定しています。
優先度は上から高い順に並べています。
プロトコル：ポート
UDP：500
UDP：1701
UDP：4500
ESP：any
51(AH)：any

繋がらない原因や、何を調べたらよいかなど、アドバイスお願いします。

Comment: wimaxのipアドレスはグローバルipですか？ならとりあえずport22を開けて、ssh -v で外部から接続した時にサーバーまで接続できてるかを確認してはどうでしょうか。あとはdnsではなくipを直接入れてみる。

Comment: @packet0 まずはSSHしようと思って調べていたら、なんか VPN の方がうまくいきました。ヒントありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wimax ルータと mydns.jp の設定を調整することで当初の目的を達成しました。

wx03 でラズパイのローカルipの22番ポート(TCP)にポートマッピング設定してから
sudo ufw allow ssh
をラズパイのシェルで実行しました。

https://xn--wimax-mt4djct122edgyc.xyz/wimax-global-ip-address.html
によると wimax ルータは外部からアクセスするには設定やら契約が必要のようです。
私の場合、プロバイダがとくとくBBなので、ルータの設定だけでよかったみたいです。
https://help.gmobb.jp/app/answers/detail/a_id/15261
から貼ってあるリンクに従いプロファイルを作成し、ルータを再起動。作成した外部接続対応のプロファイルで接続したところ、
http://www.cman.jp/network/support/port.html
からグローバル ip を直接入力して22番のポートチェックをしたら、アクセスできたと記されました。
wx03 のプロファイルを設定するまでは、アクセスできない旨が記されていました。一歩前進。

一方で、
http://www.cman.jp/network/support/port.html
の結果に表示される入力の逆引き または 正引きの項目には、ラズパイのシェルから
curl ifconfig.io
と入力して得られる値(ip確認サイトの利用者欄のipはこれと同じ値)と違う値が表示されていました。
正引きの項目に記された値は、ルータにアドレスを振る機器のグローバルアドレス？
http://www.cman.jp/network/support/ip.html
からドメイン名を入力しても同様なので、ドメイン名とグローバルアドレスが紐づいていないのかもしれないと思いました。

windows 10 cmd から ssh を試みたところ、グローバルアドレスを入力するとアクセス拒否され、 mydns.jp のドメイン名を使うと接続がタイムアウトします。

そこで mydns.jp にログインして IP ADDRESS DIRECT の IPv4 の欄に現在のラズパイのグローバルアドレス(curl ifconfig.io で得た値)を入力し、スマホから外部ネットワークを使って VPN 接続したら、接続できました。

なぜか SSH はできていない状態ですが、外部からラズパイに VPN 接続できました。
※きちんと確認していませんが、SSH できないのは windows がラズパイと同じ LAN 上からアクセスしようとしていたからみたいで、外部ネットワークからアクセスする必要があるようです。